# Camel onCompletion has null header

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a Camel route with an `onCompletion()` which then hits a `Processor`. Within this processor it gets a header from the `Exchange` but this header comes back null.

I know that `onCompletion()` runs at the end of that particular route but surely the `Exchange` headers should still be valid and usable. `inputLocation` below is defined higher up in the class and works for previous routes.

```
from("file://"+inputLocation+"?initialDelay=5000&delay=2000&recursive=true&delete=true")
    .onCompletion()
        .process(storedProcProcessor())
    .end()
    .choice()
        .when(appContext.getBean(AppPredicate.class))
            .log("Need to check against APP in the database for destination.")
            .setHeader(AppConstants.INPUTLOCATION, simple(inputLocation))
            .process(databaseProcessor())
    .endChoice();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with:

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    from("direct:start")
        .onCompletion()
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                LOG.info("Hello, {}", exchange.getIn().getHeader("myHeader"));
            }
        })
        .end()
        .setHeader("myHeader").constant("World!");
    }
}
```

This prints

> Hello, World!

Thus, the header `myHeader` is still available in `onCompletion`. So, I guess that your header is never properly set?